# como hago el merge?

Tags: python, pandas

tengo estos dataframe:

```
introducir el código aqui   
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a'+str(x) for x in range(3)],
                'B': ['b'+str(x) for x in range(3)],
                'C': ['c'+str(x) for x in range(3)]},
                 index=[0, 1, 2])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a'+str(x) for x in range(3, 6)],
                'B': ['b'+str(x) for x in range(3, 6)],
                'C': ['c'+str(x) for x in range(3, 6)]},
                 index=[3, 4, 5]) 

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['d'+str(x) for x in range(3)],
                'E': ['e'+str(x) for x in range(3)],
                'F': ['f'+str(x) for x in range(3)]},
                 index=[0, 1, 2]) 

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['d'+str(x) for x in range(3, 6)],
                'E': ['e'+str(x) for x in range(3, 6)],
                'F': ['f'+str(x) for x in range(3, 6)]},
                 index=[3, 4, 5])
```

luego los concateno:

```
introducir el código aquí
dfp=pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
dfs=pd.concat([df3, df4], ignore_index=True)
```

ahora necesito hacer merge de dfp y dfs, he tratado esto:

```
introducir el código aquí
dfn=pd.merge(dfp, dfs,left_on='C', right_on='D')
```

el merge resulta en solo los nombre de las columnas
por qué sucede esto?

Esto es lo que quisiera conseguir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor traduce pues estás en SO en español

Comment: listo! gracias por la aclaración

Comment: Hola Saul, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por defecto el merge usa la intersección entre claves y no tienes claves comunes en tus dos DataFrames ¿Podrías agregar la salida esperada de dfn?

Comment: Listo!! Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede porque por defecto el merge se hace usando la intersección de las claves (`how="inner"`), es decir, queda vacío porque para empezar ninguna de las columna a converger existe en el otro DataFrame, además de no tener valores coincidentes.

Mejor un ejemplo en el que merge con tus parámetros si haga algo:

```
import pandas as pd


dfp = pd.DataFrame({"A": (1, 2, 3, 4),
                    "C": (5, 4, 7, 8),
                    "D": (9, 10, 11, 12)})

dfs = pd.DataFrame({"E": (1, 2, 3, 4),
                    "C": (17, 13, 19, 14),
                    "D": (7, 23, 43, 71)})
```

> ```
> >>> dfp
>   A   C   D
> 0 1   5   9
> 1 2   4   10
> 2 3   7   11
> 3 4   8   12
>
> >>> dfs
>   E   C   D
> 0 1   17  7
> 1 2   13  23
> 2 3   19  43
> 3 4   14  71
> ```

```
dfn = pd.merge(dfp, dfs,left_on='C', right_on='D')
```

> ```
> >>> dfn
>   A   C_x D_x E   C_y D_y
> 0 3   7   11  1   17  7
> ```

Como podemos ver se ha quedado y se han fusionado solo la tercera fila de `dfp` y la primera de `dfs` porque en esa fila es la única en la que la columna `C` de `dfp` (`left_on`) y la `D` de `dfs` (`right_on`) **tiene el mismo valor**, 7.

Aparentemente, por el resultado deseado, solo quieres concatenar las columnas de ambos, en tal caso usa `pandas.concat` aplicado sobre el eje 1 (columnas):

```
>>> dfn = pd.concat((dfp, dfs), axis=1)
>>> dfn

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0  a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  f0
1  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1
2  a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  f2
3  a3  b3  c3  d3  e3  f3
4  a4  b4  c4  d4  e4  f4
5  a5  b5  c5  d5  e5  f5
```

Comment: Uff!! iba por el camino equivocado, pensé que se tenía que hacer un merge para poder llegar al resultado. Te agradezco mucho pues aclaraste mi mente y ahora sé algo nuevo!!

Comment: Yo cuando empecé con Pandas tenía un lio monumental con `concat`, `join` y `merge`. Especialmente con los dos últimos ... Hasta que no los entiendes tiendes a cambiar uno por otro a ver si por casualidad sale lo que quiero... XD. Un saludo.